# Opacity is showing different shades on different pages

Tags: css, opacity, rgba

I'm using opacity and it seems that it's showing as different shades on the pages I am using it on.

If you take a look here at the PS4 image: http://chrisbrighton.co.uk

...and then here at the same image... http://chrisbrighton.co.uk/Gaming.php

You'll see that there are different shades but they are all using the same CSS rules.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `#news-container` on the Gaming.php has `background: #9bd7f5;`. Since you're using `rgba()` to gain transparency, everything below or above the elements are affected by it as well.

Instead use `opacity: 0.7;` in favor of `rgba()`. The opacity property won't affect other elements.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that. I have no idea why that when you hover over #news-container it starts from the top where the hottest pages are, it should start where it says 'Latest Gaming News/Rumours Right Now...'. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that seems to be happening. It seems to be something to do with using rgba alongside opacity. If I were you I would remove the background from this class. Not only does it solve your problem but it looks a lot better from a design perspective.

```
.hot-page-title {
height: 300px;
background: rgba(255,102,000,.7);
-webkit-transition: .7s ease-in-out;
;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does this in any kind provide an answer to the question? Suggesting not to use something is fine, but it's not an answer. Also your CSS rule is closed with a `;` instead of `}`.

Comment: You'd remove the orange transparency? It's orange because them pages are the hottest so I thought I'd add a tint of orange. Removing the background removes the orange transparency, I'd like to keep that if possible. Thanks.

Comment: @Chris Yeah I'd remove the orange transparency. It makes the content look as though it is disabled/ can not be selected. I think removing that background will massively improve the usability of your site. The idea of them being orange because they are hottest is lost on the user. The hierarchy of the elements on the page itself should be a good enough indicator without the need for the orange.

Comment: @kleinfreund “Does this in any *way* provide an answer to the question?” and my answer is yes. I believe that an answer, that doesn't necessarily address the question but rather, addresses a larger problem (user experience), is still an answer worth giving.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have inspect whole code long time and #news-container  id background property affected your code.So please remove or adjust as you like .Hope the answer!